# Oracle XE 11g homepage not displaying

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle11g, listener

I have been searching for a solution to my problem for a while now but none seems to be working, this is my last attempt before I go for re-installation.

I today installed Oracle XE 11g Release 2 through its installation wizard and it went fine. The trouble I seem to be having is that I can't open the browser homepage.

The browsers are giving me the error: `cannot establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080`

I am on Windows 7 32-bit and i have downloaded & installed the XE for the same.

From reading all the possible answers I gathered that some info might be needed before my question is answered. So are the results from various commands that I have run which all the answers asked for.

1)

```
C:\Users\lenove> netstat -nao | find "8080"
```

No result for this one

2)

```
C:\Users\lenovo> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 18-JAN-2013 16:46:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                18-JAN-2013 16:18:54
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 27 min. 52 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Voldemort\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Voldemort)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

3)

```
SQL> SELECT dbms_xdb.gethttpport FROM dual;
SP2-0640 : Not Connected
```

4)
Contents of oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.20/server/network/ADMIN/listener.ora (oraclexe is the default installation directory suggested by the Installation Wizard)

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Voldemort)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I tried using both chrome and firefox (latest versions of both) but still couldn't get it.

**Note:** This is my first attempt at oracle so I was a bit wary of trying every solution suggested by the threads, hence my own thread.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: can you connect to db via command line sqlplus ?

Comment: @maialithar No, I am getting: `ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress` when I try to connect through SYSTEM and an `SP2-0640: Not connected` through anything else

Comment: you should be able to connect as `sys` user in such case. if you do, try `shutdown abort` and wait for the db to close. if it doesn't, it means you messed up your installation.

Comment: @maialithar Still getting `ORA-01033` error `process id: 0 session id: 0 serial number: 0`. What should I do now? Re-installation?

Comment: you can try restarting db service in windows or your machine - if db won't boot then, you should reinstall it

Comment: @maialithar I have already rebooted my laptop twice after installation. I think that amounts to restarting the services. So i should try re-installation now?

Comment: yes, you should reinstall.

Comment: "SQL> startup mount" without quotes worked for me 2 have successful connection...

Comment: "SQL> connect sys/password as sysdba" also helped me to fix problem

Answer (score 1):

I installed on a Windows 7 pro (under local administrator account) and it ran smooth. I installed the exact same bundle on a Windows 7 Home Premium (the UAC prompts for elevation to local ADMIN) and I had the issue: no XE home page.

You shall check first that windows services (via control panel > Admin tools > services) OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener are indeed started.

You can then check (as illustrated in top post) the TNS listner status with (adjust \Oracle\XE to your installation path)

```
C:\Oracle\XE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\lsnrctl status
```

which yields the *Listening Endpoints*, and if you do not see **three** lines like (the third one likely missing !):

```
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=BHPPC)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=BHPPC)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
```

then that's exactly where the problem is. The trick is to take note of the host name on which the TNS service listens (e.g. BHPPC in the above example). Then do add en entry into your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` like (on a line of its own, no space before 127.0.0.1, followed by spaces or tab, followed by your hostname):

```
 127.0.0.1  BHPPC
```

and restart both windows services listed above. Check again the *Listening Endpoints* with the `lsnrctl status` command; if the magical third line is now listed, the XE home page will work. There's indeed a bug in hostname resolution and you shall provide the TNS service with an explicit IP address mapping which, surprisingly, it doesn't need to listen OK to port 1521.

Comment: This information helped me, thanks! It ended up that 127.0.0.1 was not being listened to (I inherited a pre-installed XE, so no idea if that is an install issue or just default behavior in the version I have), so I ended up just using the HTTP://myservername:8080/apex/ URL, which then worked. I did not bother with the HOSTS file, as I prefer to leave that empty.

Comment: With yet another installation I noted that when Oracle XE doesn't listen OK on the web port as explained here, it will too fail to accept connections via port 1521, even when this port is listed by e.g. "netstat" command with a listening Oracle process on it. I suspect that the same cause (the missing hosts entry) affect both the Web port and connection listener operations, yet in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to proceed to the installation from a **local** administrative user.

On my computer : windows 7 professional, 64 bits

- connected with user from a domain, in Administrative group : installation fail, without any message. In the log files located in **/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/config/log**, I found a lot of "not connected" messages (sorry, I did not keep the log files)
- connected with local administrative user : installation works and menu getStarted works : browser display the Oracle Database XE 11.2 administration home page.